# Custom Appbar not changing colour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

The appbar remains translucent even though i've colorPrimaryDark defined in the styles of my custom theme. The significant part of the code is as follows.

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

This is where i've a toolbar in appbar layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/appBar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" android:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And this is what i've defined in the manifest for that activity:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity5"
            android:label="Activity5"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.divya.sampleapplication.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Any suggestions on where i'm going wrong. Everything else like the toolbars and all are working fine.

Comment: just add <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: What is theme in <application> tag in manifest?

Comment: Apptheme. android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to change this line

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

To

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="AppTheme" />
```

Comment: tried that. not working. on the contrary, the title colour changed to black. reverted back the changes.

Comment: Good Luck ,hope u will find the answer